# Placing the Images in between the Post Content

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on wordpress site where my query is I want to place some three images inside the post content after each paragraph. I know that it can be done by using the text editor provide by the wordpress, but after few days we will be changing the images and in my blog I have more than 50 article and I don't want to go on each article and change the images has it is time consuming. So is there any code where I can put the for all the three images after each paragrapph. This is the code I have found in the theme.

```
<div class="<?php echo implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'hu_single_entry_class', array('entry','themeform') ) ) ?>">
    <div class="entry-inner">
     <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Please suggest me how do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your images after content.so put images after `<?php the_content(); ?>` just like this.

edit  **single.php**

```
<div class="<?php echo implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'hu_single_entry_class', array('entry','themeform') ) ) ?>">
    <div class="entry-inner">
     <?php the_content(); ?>
<img src="imagelink here" alt="" height="" width="">
<img src="imagelink here" alt="" height="" width="">
<img src="imagelink here" alt="" height="" width="">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is the images has to be placed in middle of the content. How to do it.

Comment: When you post, all your post going to mysql database in 1 column as 1 file. so when you call the post by `the_content()` function, it will call your post from database. so technically you cant put any other things between that post.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want add common 3 images on every post (i.e `single.php`)

    then you can use like this

    <div class="<?php echo implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'hu_single_entry_class', array('entry','themeform') ) ) ?>">
        <div class="entry-inner">
         <?php the_content(); ?>
    <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="" alt=""></a>
    <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="" alt=""></a>
    <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    </div>

    If you want change the images in future so you can change the path here.

    If you want different images on each post so you can do it by suing advance custom field (`ACF`)

    Link- https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

    By using create field and fetch on `single.php` page

    for fetching image use 

    <?php $field = get_field($field_name, $post_id, $format_value); ?>

    I hope this will help you.

    Thank you.
```

Comment: VIpin, this is not my solution. I want to insert the images in between the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
i think you can do this by using Advance custom field. (ACF)

    Steps find below:

    1.create a field for content (the content before image) on single .php
    2.create image field by using ACF or reapter field and fetch in on single.php page
    3.create a field for content(the content after images) on single .php

    You can fetch both the conetnt field and images here so for every post you have to ad content but for images you can chnages the images once so it will reflect to your all post.

    I hope this will you.

    Thank you
```